# USB PD multiple voltages simultaneously

Tags: usb-pd

I haven’t been to stack overflow in a loooong time, it’s nice to be back!

I was just wondering if USB Power Delivery can provide multiple different voltages simultaneously… say, 5V & 9V, on two different rails.

If not, could someone please point me in the right direction to figure out how to make a custom circuit to get the voltages/amps I need?

Thanks so much for any help in advance!

Hope everyone is having fun with their electronics projects!

Comment: Pointer --> use two voltage regulators teed off from the main incoming supply.

Comment: Ehm, this isn't Stack Overflow.

Comment: "_two different rails_" ... could you clarify which conductors you're hoping these two rails will be presented on?

Comment: PD does not output different voltages simultaneously, it outputs  the voltages one at a time. The PD type-C port has only one output, VBUS. 5V first, then according to negotiated contract.

Comment: lol, sorry Transistor, I thought it all fell under the same umberella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB-PD allows for one voltage.

You can make any voltages you want yourself from that one voltage.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn’t too sure about USB PD & its full capabilities.